# Dynamically writing Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic

I am creating dynamic sites with the same code base, where I will need to display the appropriate Google ads Javascript code, based on some logic.

In my .Net 4, MVC3 environment, I have setup the following scenario:

Navigating to www.mysite.com/script_processor/ returns the following text:

```
function doAlert(v1, v2){alert('Called alert()' + v1 + ' : ' + v2);}
```

This text come out of my model as such:

```
page.stringResponse = "function doAlert(v1, v2){alert('Called alert()' + v1+ ' : ' + v2);}";
```

I can then do something like this from a separate site/page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/script_processor/">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    doAlert('string 1', 'string 2');
</script>
```

As you would expect, I get an alert box with "Called alert() string 1 : string 2", so the function on mysite.com is accessible from site 2.

Obviously when I do a view source form the page, I only see the doAlert() call, and not the content of the function that sits on mysite.com.

Now, instead of doAlert() on mysite.com, I want to have a function that dynamically writes out javascript that can will be seen on site 2 when it's called.

I created a model method:

```
public GetResponsePage GetPageResponse(string V1, string V2)
{
    var page = new GetResponsePage();
    page.stringResponse = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.write('testing injected Javascript.');alert('value of v1: " + V1 + "value of v2: " + V2 + "');</script>";
    return page;
}
```

When navigating to the route, I see the popup, and the "testing injected Javascript." on the page.

When I reference this from site 2, I don't see the popup, nor do I see "testing injected Javascript" in the page source.

As I mentioned I will later replace this with the JS code for the appropriate Google Ads js code.

I don't think this is working quite right... what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: If your goal is to be able to include an external javascript on a page and have that external javascript alter the content of the page so that you see the altered contents when you do a view source, it won't work.

Comment: No, I just want to dynamically set the javascript that gets displayed on the page.  So the request comes in to /script_processor/, and returns the appropriate Javascript that needs to be visible from the site calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ever evil `eval` to dynamically execute JavaScript.  The JavaScript you pass in can also declare functions.

```
eval("function doAlert(v1, v2){alert('Called alert()' + v1 + ' : ' + v2);}");
```

I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to accomplish, but you could put an eval call like this wherever you want:

```
function createDoAlertFunction(){
    eval("function doAlert(v1, v2){alert('Called alert()' + v1 + ' : ' + v2);}");
}
```

Just note though, that this should be **avoided**.  Stick to declaring your functions the old fashioned way, like you already are.

**EDIT**

Oh, you want *MVC* to to inject JavaScript dynamically.  MVC has a *JavaScriptResult*, but it looks like its use is strongly, **strongly** discouraged.

Nonetheless, here's a [link](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2009/02/07/beware-of-asp-net-mvc-javascriptresult.aspx) that shows its use

```
public ActionResult DoSomething() {  
   string s = "$('#some-div').html('Updated!');";  
   return JavaScript(s);  
}
```

and why it's not a good idea

Comment: Updated with more details above.

Comment: Thanks for the info on eval... I've stayed away from this in the past.  What I'm trying to accomplish is when making the js reference, that the response from  www.mysite.com/script_processor/ is visible to say, Google/etc.  From my tests above, I know that the script is accessible, and that I can pass variables to script_processor that will allow me to add the appropriate js response text.  With that reference on site 1 the script_processor, how can I verify that the script is loaded and visible, when all I see is the reference in the code?

Comment: @ElHaix - ahh, I see.  Let's say there's a global variable called `x` declared in a script, and you want to know if this script has been loaded.  The best way would be to check to see if x exists, which you can do like this `if (typeof x === "undefined") alert("not loaded");`

Comment: @ Adam - Makes sense.  I was part way there with the alert() test.  Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @ElHaix - sure.  And x can be a function and that'll work fine.  So for your example you could test whether doAlert has been created with `if (typeof doAlert === "undefined") alert("not loaded");`

Comment: @ Adam.  Will verify all that, thanks.  Just to verify the page load lifecycle, during the load process: as long as the content type returned from script_processor (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.com/script_processor"></script>) is text and is valid Javascript, it will be executed.  ie.  On pages that have the src="xxxx.js" - navigating to this URL shows the text value of the JS.  This is a bit of new turf for me, so just want to verify.  I'll look up some articles on js lifecycle...Thanks.

Comment: @ElHaix - I think that's correct.  If you have a web page that's rendered with valid script tags that point to X.js, then yes, the script in that file will be executed.

Comment: @ Adam - When loading js on the page, are there browsers that require the .js extension, or will all browsers attempt to load anything referenced in <script type="text/javascript" src="[path to some script that is returned as simple text]"></script>; ?  With my MVC architecture I can return the required js text through a route, not requiring the .js extension.  If this is required, would the addition of querystring parameters hinder the script loading if some browsers require the .js extension?

Comment: @ElHaix - I'm really not sure.  I would recommend asking a new question on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late. But there is very easy way to send JavaScript from controller.

```
 @Html.Raw("<script>" + @ViewBag.DynamicScripts + "</script>")
```

In controller send JavaScript as follows:

```
 ViewBag.DynamicScripts = "alert('test');";
```